# AWS Kinesis consumer client for android

Tags: android, amazon-kinesis

I need to consume AWS Kinesis data on my Android app for displaying real time data. There is a consumer client library available for java,.NET etc but not for android. I have created a consumer in Java successfully but how can I get it for Android if there is no library in android.